# CSS Filters not working (apart from one)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently playing around with CSS Filters and cannot understand why only one out of four of my filters are working.

I currently have 4 images in divs, 2 at the top and 2 at the bottom. Each image is floated right with border and padding; I've created this as an #id. I'm then applying 4 CSS Filters to the images as classes but only grayscale is working.

I cannot understand why only grayscale is working as all ids are unique (and they are working as images have floated) and one of the classes, grayscale, has worked perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            div {
                vertical-align: top;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 500px;
                border: 2px solid #000;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

            }

            #img1 {
                float: right;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;

            }

            #img2 {
                float: right;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;

            }

            #img3 {
                float: right;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;

            }

            #img4 {
                float: right;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;

            }

            .sepia {
                -webkit-filter: sepia(5000);
            }

            /* this class works*/
            .grayscale {
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
            }

            .blur {
                -webkit-filter: blur(1000px);
            }

            .contrast {
                -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Sepia</h2>
            <img id="img1" class="sepia" src="images/owl.jpg" alt="This is an owl" width="250" height="250">
        </div>

        <div>
        <!-- this works perfectly-->
            <h2>Grayscale</h2>
            <img id="img2" class="grayscale" src="images/owl.jpg" alt="This is an owl" width="250" height="250">
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Blur</h2>
            <img id="img3" class="blur" src="images/owl.jpg" alt="This is an owl" width="250" height="250">
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Contrast</h2>
            <img id="img4" class="contrast" src="images/owl.jpg" alt="This is an owl" width="250" height="250">
        </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the vendor prefix (`-webkit-`) from `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked this out; I was using the wrong values as I thought all filter values were between 0 to 1.

blur uses px:

```
filter: blur(5px);
```

contrast can use %:

```
filter: contrast(200%);
```